# Total sum across wide range of specific cells

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

Okay, so suppose we have the data set up like so:

[image: data set up]

```
Area 1             10 sq m
    Wall 1          5 sq m
    Wall 2          6 sq m
    Wall 3          5 sq m
    Wall 4          6 sq m
Area 2             21 sq m
    Wall 1          7 sq m
    Wall 2          4 sq m
        Window 1    2 sq m
    Wall 3          7 sq m
        Window 2    2 sq m
    Wall 4          4 sq m
```

And in another sheet, the data is to be presented like so:

[image: data summary]

```
Total interior wall area    __ sq m
    Area 1                  __ sq m
    Area 2                  __ sq m
Total floor area            __ sq m
    Area 1                  __ sq m
    Area 2                  __ sq m
```

How would I do this automatically?
What I was thinking is:

1. Look for cells with a specific tag (like "wall") in them
2. Get the number value to the right, under the "AREA" column
3. Get the sum of all those values

My problem with this algorithm is that I do not know how to execute it, not knowing the specific functions needed. Or, maybe there are other ways to do this with specific functions that I do not know of. Thank you very much to those who would answer, this is my first question on this website.

Comment: Test sheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WwHQ6XvsdVR0Lox5MrBJ8Qq8pnnTL6RLnkIMuymJuqs/edit?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({SUM(FILTER(D1:D, REGEXMATCH(LOWER(B1:B), "wall"))); 
 QUERY({IF(A1:A<>"", A1:A, IF(B1:B="",,VLOOKUP(ROW(A1:A), 
 IF(A1:A<>"", {ROW(A1:A), A1:A}), 2, 1))), B1:B, D1:D}, 
 "select sum(Col3) 
  where lower(Col2) contains 'wall' 
  group by Col1 
  label sum(Col3)''", 0)})
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Well I wasn't prepared for this wizardry ._. But alright. I'll try to understand this and further adapt it to whatever else I might use. Thanks!